# Using two Apple Developer Accounts to work on an Xcode project collaboratively using git

Tags: ios, xcode, git, provisioning-profile, provisioning

Is it possible for two **seperate individual** Apple Developer accounts to work on one single Xcode project, using two Macs, without provisioning profiles being revoked?

I understand it is **not** possible for an individual Apple Developer account to have two users working on two separate machines using the single account as provisioning profiles are revoked.

As we will be using git to work on the application, the question is if we are using two Apple Developer accounts, will this ensure that provisioning profiles are not revoked and will this allow us to work on the project collaboratively using git?

Comment: You're provisioning profiles won't get revoked. Just make sure after you pull from git that you select your own certificate and profile in the build settings.

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't run into any issue with your provisioning profile being revoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never experienced an issue with this but I've also always used a good Xcode .gitignore by default https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/Xcode.gitignore that you should include in every .git that holds an Xcode project (i.e. add it to your initial commit when creating the project).

Any application can only be published to the app store under a single developer account, so you should decide now if you want create to a team for the account (business) or if only one of you will be responsible for publishing it to and maintaining it on the app store (common for side projects).

For testing, a developer can use any provisioning profile they have access to in order to push builds to test devices (though the device must be set up to trust builds from each provisioning profile that pushes to it).